# maven generated pom.properties file add date property

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Interested to know if it's possible to amend the pom.properties file created by maven to include the date as a property it currently looks like:

```
#Generated by Maven
#Thu Jul 26 15:13:53 BST 2018
version=3.2
groupId=com.blah.blah
artifactId=example
```

Comment: Note that newer versions of maven (like 3.9.3) by default don't write the first 2 lines to pom.properties.